# Determining which records to return based on data structure in a field

Tags: sql

If I have a field that includes many values like

```
67495837431978432 ABC1234
```

and other values like

```
1234 Something Street
```

(I know the data shouldn't be like this. It isn't my database. Can't be changed. Please disregard.)

How can I only return records that have data in this field like the former?

I've tried

```
where SUBSTRING(field, 1, 10) LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

with my thought being if the first type of value starts with 17 numbers, and the next type is a street address with many letters in the first 10 characters, I should be able to check if the first 10 characters only include numbers, and return the field based on that, and I should only get back records like

```
67495837431978432 ABC1234
```

as I desire to. Not the cleanest, but should work fine for my situation. But that didn't work. I can't see why. Am I making an error I'm not seeing? Is there a better way to do this that is relatively simple?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: I apologize. Noted.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: I had it tagged sql-server, but Gordon Linoff removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server and you want to check that the first ten characters are digits, you can use `like` with character classes:

```
where field LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: I've tried this too, and it seems like this should bring back a record that has the value "47456785432145678 CBF714" in the field, for example, but it doesn't. It's not getting returned.